# Localization of interpolated parts in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, localization, devise

i'm using devise for authentication, and i need to fully localize it's messages.

I'm just mirror devise.en.yml file to different languages, but i don't know, how to translate interpolated parts, like this:

> inactive_signed_up: 'You have signed up successfully. However, we could not sign you in because your account is %{reason}.'

I've created german version (devise.de.yml):

> inactive_signed_up: "Willcommen ! Sie haben ihre registrierung fertig zu machen. Ihre user ist %{reason}."

And got following message:

```
"Willcommen ! Sie haben ihre registrierung fertig zu machen. Ihre user ist %{reason}."
```

In place, where **%{reason}** is located, i get untranslated english word **unconfirmed**.

How to translate it properly ?

**Update 1**

Is there any way to insert ruby code into yaml, like this:

> "Willcommen ! Sie haben ihre registrierung fertig zu machen. Ihre user ist %{I18n.t reason}."

When this approach will work, i just need to have unconfirmed key declared in yaml:

```
unconfirmed: inactiv
```

Answer (score 0):

Most times, we use variables inside strings in order to pass information like numbers or generally data that does not need translation. If it was something that would need translation, i would probably just include the reasons as another i18n record, like :

```
en:
  reasons:
    i_see_you_as_a_friend: ... 
    you_are_like_a_brother_to_me: ..
```

And use that accordingly :)

Comment: OK, i understand, what you mean. This format of messages is created by "devise" gem. How to fully translate a message in my case ?

Comment: you could change the format of devise messages to reflect that technique.

Comment: For example, you can change the messages so that there is inactive_signup_banned_user : "You have signed up successfully. However, we could not sign you in because your account is banned". That is, based on the reason, provide another message.